# Linux on Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E

Tags: ubuntu, networking, internet, sony-vaio, linux-mint

I bought Sony Vaio VPCEB1S1E and I was able to surf on net. Then I tried to install Ubuntu 9.04 and Linux Mint on it but neither allows me an access to the Internet. How can I configure Mint so that I can go to net and get updates via apt-get?

```
jaakko@jaakko-laptop ~ $ ifconfig -a
lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:720 (720.0 B) TX bytes:720 (720.0 B)

pan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 46:83:d4:f4:36:bc
BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 78:dd:08:c5:61:88
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wmaster0 Link encap:UNSPEC HWaddr 78-DD-08-C5-61-88-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
UP RUNNING MTU:0 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

jaakko@jaakko-laptop ~ $ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Let's clarify this a little bit. I see from your ifconfig that you don't seem to have a wired ethernet port, is that correct? If you do have one, try typing ifup eth0, and see if that helps. Or are you just trying to connect over wireless? Wireless connections from the command line *are* possible, but they are deep magic.

Comment: I would like to have a wired connection and I was able to get that on Windows. ifup eth0 says ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0

Answer (score 0):

I have the same notebook and I don't recall doing any special setup for my wireless.  The wired interface is however not found by Ubuntu.  But maybe the new Lucid might work?

Comment: Strange. I don't know why my network won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would execute the following to find out what type of NIC/Wifi Card you have in your Linux laptop and then begin looking for the appropriate drivers, guides to get it working properly.

To being execute this command to see the information:

```
$  lspci
```

To give you an idea of the output, here is the hardware to my laptop based off of the above command.

```
brendan@synergy:~$ lspci
```

- 12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
- 13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)